# Unable to boot Windows after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC and the installation completed well.
But now the problem is I am unable to boot Windows 8, in GRUB menu it shows both options, If I choose Ubuntu, it boots smoothly and if I choose Windows 8 it shows the following message:

```
error: device format "ldm/958e9087-d9d5-11e2-be71-0024d7280798/Volume1" invalid : must be (f|h) dN, with 0<= N < 128  

press any key to continue...
```

and after some seconds...  it shows :

A disk read error
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to restart.

Comment: if you have uefi-Bios ( to get to Bios-Settings press at start of booting one of 'Function'-keys as to see in starting screen - which one to press ) - disable Uefi-Bios and enable Efi-Bios - for more details about UEFI - see here : help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Congrats and welcome to Ubuntu. I once destroyed someones windows partition in an attempt to make a dual-boot machine. This person had to go cold-turkey from windows to Ubuntu, but thanked me later for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable `SecureBoot` in your BIOS ( see this paragraph )
2. Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Disabling_SecureBoot_in_the_BIOS)'s `Recommended Repair`
3. Reboot, you should be able to access both Ubuntu and Windows.