# Windows 8 failed to boot - Dual boot Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Can someone help me with this?

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8. Ubuntu boots perfectly, but when I select Windows 8 from the grub bootloader, I get the following error message:

```
error: device format "ldm/94094a20-f13b-11e0-808c-005056c00008/Volume1" invalid:
 must  be (f|h)dN, with 0 <= N < 128

press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have UEFI-Bios get to Bios-Settings disable Uefi-Bios and enable Efi-Bios

You seem to have similar [problem like this](https://askubuntu.com/q/310944/190009)

Check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/190009) this might help you

Comment: Boot-repair did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might have mistakenly deleted essential boot files in the windows folder. Since Ubuntu gives you the ability to access and read and write files in the C:\ folder, its possible that you might alter Windows system files, which are generally unalterable when using microsoft widows.
This problem might also arise due to the use of Partitioning Applications, like *gparted*, to partition the main windows drive from ubuntu
Its possible is that you resized the ubuntu partition either using a partitioning app of some sort, or during installation, and the resize ate in into the windows system. This is a fatal error, and is seriously hard to resolve.
If you have a windows installation disc, put it into your disc drive and restart your machine and try to boot to windows, and then try the "System Restore" option

Comment: Boot repair fixed the issue. Thanks nevertheless.